# Xmobar plugins stuck at updating and glyph fonts not working

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I have been trying to get my head around xmobar with xmonad on Arch. Some things work and some I just cant get to work.

1. I cannot for the life of my get glyph fonts to work/appear even when they are installed on the system.
2. Some of plugins - Battery, Network, Xmonadlog and Wireless just hang at "updating" while others; CPU, swap, date etc work just fine.

There are no errors coming up in xsessions.error log.

My `.xmobarrc` file:

```hs
  1 Config { additionalFonts = [ "xft:FontAwesome-4:size=11:antilias=true" ]
  2         , border    = TopB
  3         , alpha     = 255
  4         , allDesktops = True
  5         , font      = "xft:iosevka-9"
  6         , bgColor   = "#5f5f5f"
  7         , fgColor   = "#f8f8f2"
  8         , position  = TopW L 100  -- Top with fixed width 100% left aligned.
  9         , overrideRedirect  = True
 10         , lowerOnStart      = True
 11         , persistent        = True
 12         , commands  = [ Run Cpu
 13                           [ "-L", "3"
 14                           , "-H", "50"
 15                           , "--high"  , "red"
 16                           , "--normal", "green"
 17                           ] 10
 18                         , Run Network "enp2s0f0" ["-t", "<fn=1>\xf8f5</fn>
 19 <rx>kb <fn=1>\xfa51</fn> <tx>kb"] 20
 20                         , Run Wireless "wlan0" [ "-t", "<essid>" ] 10
 21                         , Run Alsa "default" "Master"
 22                             [ "--template", "v: <volumestatus>"
 23                             , "--suffix"  , "True"
 24                             , "--"
 25                             , "--on", ""
 26                             ]
 27                         , Run Memory ["--template", "Mem: <usedratio>%"
 28                                       , "-L", "0"
 29                                       , "-H", "70"
 30                                       , "--high", "red"
 31                                       , "--normal", "green" ] 10
 32                         , Run Swap [] 10
 33                         , Run Date "<fn=1>\xe62b</fn> %a  %d-%m-%Y  <fc=#8be9fd>%H:%M</fc>" "date" 10
 34                         , Run Com "uname" ["-s","-r"] "" 36000
 35                         , Run XMonadLog
 36                       -- battery monitor
 37                         , Run Battery [ "--template" , "Batt: <acstatus>"
 38                                       , "--Low"      , "10"        -- units: %
 39                                       , "--High"     , "80"        -- units: %
 40                                       , "--low"      , "darkred"
 41                                       , "--normal"   , "darkorange"
 42                                       , "--high"     , "darkgreen"
 43                                       , "--" -- battery specific options
 44                                         -- discharging status
 45                                       , "-o"  , "<left>% (<timeleft>)"
 46                                        -- AC "on" status
 47                                       , "-O"  , "<fc=#dAA520>Charging</fc>"
 48                                        -- charged status
 49                                       , "-i"  , "<fc=#006000>Charged</fc>"
 50                              ] 50
 51                       ]
 52         , sepChar    = "%"
 53         , alignSep   = "}{"
 54         , template   = " %uname%  |  %XMonadLog%  | %Battery%}{  %alsa:default:Master%  |  %cpu%
 55 |  %memory%  |  %swap%  |  %network%  | %Wireless% |  %date%  "
 56         }
```

Do you need to do some magical other things to get glyph fonts and those hanging plugins working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Glyphs

Adding the glyphs as characters works for me, i.e. `<fn=1></fn>` instead of `<fn=1>\xf8f5</fn>`. (The glyph won't show correctly here on StackOverflow, though...)

###### Plugins

`Network "enp2s0f0" []` requires you to use `%enp2s0f0%`, not `%network%`.

Likewise but with the added suffix `wi`, `Wireless "wlan0" []` requires you to use `%wlan0wi%`, not `%Wireless%`.

I don't use `Battery` and `XMonadLog` but the Codeberg documentation on [Plugins and monitors](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org) probably provides some useful information for [Battery](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org#headline-4) and [XMonadLog](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org#headline-61).

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my network and wifi status. My glypths still dont display correctly even using the actual glyph and even following the documentation for BatteryP it is stuck on updating. I can manually `cat` the battery capacity to xmobar though. Is there some way of knowing if a plugin is actually installed with xmobar? It's not throwing any errors no matter what I do which makes debugging kind of annoying...

Comment: I figured it out. BatteryP aliases to battery in the template. The non-standardised naming conventions for plugins in the template are really throwing me.

Comment: @tanbog Yes. If you have installed `xmobar` using `pacman`, all of [these](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmobar-0.44.1/docs/src/) should be usable.